# Django - How to render html and return a json at the same time

Tags: json, django, view, rendering

I have a view which populate a json object, and then, at the end of the same view I would render an html page, but also return the final json.

probably this is not relevant but the json would be for example something like this:

```
{
    "embedToken": "dasfgjasdàgjasdàgasdàgèe-AveryLongToken",
    "embedUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/let's_go_to_the_lake",
    "reportId": "e615-sfash-9746"
}
```

the line I'm not able to fix (tried all day with all alternatives methods) is the following:

```
return render(request, "home.html", jsn)
```

my url.py is simple as follow:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView, name='home'),
]
```

I currently get the following error:

> context must be a dict rather than str.

But I encountered all different kinds of errors on the way without succeeding to reach the desired result(rendering the html and returning the json at the same time). So my doubt is that I'm taking the wrong approach at the basics, should I change road?

I would like to try to convert the json into a dictionary, and then maybe convert it back in a json in JavaScript

I have also tried to split my requests, by rendering the html as a Django view, and performing the function call from JavaScript ajax request as follow:

```
function handler1(){
    // there are many other methods like $.get $.getJSON
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'json',
       url: "http://piedpiper.com/api/callers"
    }).then(function(result) {
        // do something with the result

    });
}
```

But I ended up by understanding that in this way I must create the URL api/callers which will be available/reachable to everybody, which I cannot do, because of the user session. only the logged in user must see the json data

Comment: This is the native nature of an http request. One request, one response. Not two responses. You should change your logic around that. One request for the html and another for the json.

Comment: please nik check out my update on question, what do you think?

Comment: Could you provide more detail about your need? You cant expect two response from one view. Each view can return an HTML page or JSON response. I think it is better to return an HTML page in the first view, then in that HTML you can call an ajax to get json value from another view.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the proper arguments on render. [Here is the docs for render function in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

Here is a sample code of a view

```py
def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "share_string": share_string,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
```